# Count duplicate values and display each different value from mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table (`url_log`) with a column (`referer`) of urls. Some urls are unique and some are duplicates. Using PHP I want to display each different url (without repeating) and the number of times the url appears in the column.

This is what I came up with but it is definitely wrong:

```
echo '<table>';

$ref=$icdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(referer) AS frequency, referer FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$dom."' GROUP BY referer ORDER BY frequency DESC");

foreach ($ref as $details) {
echo "<tr><td>".$details['referer']."</td><td>".$details['frequency']."</td></tr>";
}

echo '</table>';
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why PHP? Use MySQLs `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`. Much faster and less code.

Comment: can you add some sample data and desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(referer), COUNT(referer) AS frequency
FROM url_log 
GROUP BY referer
ORDER BY frequency DESC;
```

Comment: I used:

`$result= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(referer), COUNT(referer) AS frequency FROM url_log WHERE u = '".$page."' GROUP BY referer ORDER BY frequency DESC");

while ($details=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$details['referer']."</td><td>".$details['COUNT(referer)']."</td></tr>";
}`

But I can't seem to display the count

Comment: Change: $details['COUNT(referer)'] to $details['frequency']

Comment: No problem, sometimes just needs a second pair of eyes on it. You're welcome to up my comment too if it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

for selecting each different value of a column use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column) AS columnname_key FROM table ;
```

to count duplicate use this code

```
SELECT Count(*) duplicatetable
FROM
(
    select columname_to_check_dulicate_values, Count(*)
    from tablename
    group by name
    having Count(*) > 1
) x
```